# How to handle event in C++/CLI

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Can someone help me fix my function? I'm trying make an event handler but I don't know what is wrong with my code, so here it is:

```
private: System::Void progressBar(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e System::Windows::Forms::WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser->ProgressChanged
 {
     // code here....
 }
```

I hope someone can help me because I have already looked in web and some forums but I can't get any luck and I can't find a good example for my code.

Comment: What's wrong is that you don't have any code.

Comment: @siride Looks like he has code. I see some in the question. Problem is, it won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your current event-handler function definition:

1. The syntax you use to declare the second argument is invalid. You have this:

   ```
   EventArgs^ e WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs
   ```

   The `e` parameter is declared to be of type `EventArgs^`, then you added a random other type after it (`WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs`). This is going to result in a compiler error because the compiler doesn't know what to make of it because it doesn't belong there.

   If you want `e` to be of type `WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs`, you need to move that to the beginning and remove `EventArgs`.

   Remember that `WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs` is a subclass of `EventArgs` (which you can tell because it ends with the same name, a common naming convention in WinForms), so everything `EventArgs` has and can do, so can `WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs`. The compiler already knows this, so you don't need to tell it.

   The correct declaration of argument `e`, then, is this:

   ```
   WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs^ e
   ```
2. As far as I know, the `Handles` keyword (added after the definition of an event handler method) exists *only* in VB.NET. So the following is invalid:

   ```
   Handles WebBrowser->ProgressChanged
   ```

   In other languages (like C++/CLI and C#), you need to wire up the event handler manually through code. That looks like this:

   ```
   obj->Event += gcnew EventHandler(this, Obj_Event);
   ```

So, putting it all together, the proper signature for an event handler method is:

```
Void progressBar(Object^ sender, WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs^ e)
{
    // code goes here...
}
```

And somewhere else, you need to wire up this event handler method to an event, like so:

```
WebBrowser->ProgressChanged += gcnew WebBrowserProgressChangedEventArgs(this, progressBar);
```